# extra drone 0.5 github check on all my PRs?

Tags: github, drone.io

I keep getting an extra check on my PRs titled

```
continuous-integration/drone
```

that never has a detail popup. I don't have any webhooks beyond the drone 0.5 installation.

How can I turn this off, or is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this is because you are using protected branches, with `continuous-integration/drone` as a required check. GitHub will automatically add required checks (with no detail) when the PR is first created.

In 0.5 the check name changed to `continuous-integration/drone/pr`

I believe the solution is therefore to remove `continuous-integration/drone` from the required check, and then add the newer `continuous-integration/drone/pr` value.

Comment: of course! Yes the /drone one is added automatically, so I just removed it and changed to /drone/pr everywhere